# Is there any way to provide transaction rollback in Mono.zip?

Tags: spring-webflux

I am working on an orchestration layer Microservice where I need to call a few APIs of different microservices in parallel. For that I am making use of `subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel)` and subscribing to each response in `Mono.zip`. For example:

```
Mono<A> a =  service1.api().subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<B> b =  service2.api().subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Mono<C> c =  service3.api().subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
return Mono.zip(a,b,c);
```

Now AFAIK, this zip will fail if any of the `a`, `b` OR `c` completes with an error. Assume that something went wrong in the third call, I want to handle this case in such a way that any operation done by `service1.api()` and `service2.api()` could be reverted, i.e. rolled-back like a transaction.

I apologize for any wrong statement I've made as I am a bit new in Spring WebFlux. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Look at R2DBC, it has this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such provision to rollback individual calls. You can make use of Mono.zipDelayError to let complete the valid calls except the one which could fail. After that, on error return you can go for individual transaction rollback with explicitly implementing the same.